# Python wont run with Task Scheduler but will run normally?

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system, directory

For some reason, which totally blows my mind, I have a python program that won’t work when I have the windows Task Scheduler run it.  I just updated the program, and while it ran successfully EVERY time before, it fails every time now.
The really strange thing is if I run the python script independent of the Task Scheduler, it works just fine!

So the main difference between the old program and the new program is the old one used urllib.request and the new one runs locally with open(), os.listdir, and os.path.join
When I run the program through windows Task Scheduler, the result on the Scheduler says “(0x1)” and also a Windows CMD window flashes up saying:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File “C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Test\Client\Beige.py” , line 16 in (module)
For filename in os.listdir(‘Website_Check”):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError3]  the system cannot find the path specified:
“Website_Check”
```

So basically, when I run the program straight up, it accesses the external .txt file just fine, but from Task Scheduler it doesn’t?  I need help.  Anyone else have any experience with this one?

(I know I could just store the txt file in the same directory and not a subdir, but I have to have another folder with another program modifying the txt file every day)

Comment: By the way, my code is fine as it works normally outside of Task Scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are using absolute paths in your program, and not relative ones. Task Scheduler is probably running your program from a different directory, and if you have relative paths in your program it is not able to find them. One easy way around this is to put the following line at the top of your program (assuming you've already imported `os`):

```
os.chdir("c:/Users/User/Documents/Python/Test/Client")
```

Now, all the commands below are being run from this directory, and relative paths should work.

Comment: Ahhhhh you are so smart.... I am eternally grateful:) lol  It's always the easiest solutions that totally slip my mind!